# C#, my program stops running after the function runs, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++

This is for cs50 mario pyramid problem set. I had it working without a function, but i wanted to try something different. Since the change after the user enters the number, that fits the parameters, the program stops. it will not print the "#", or the " " like it used to.

I am taking this course for fun online, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int towerheight(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("how high would you like the tower? ");
    int height = towerheight();
    int pound;
    int space;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (space = height - i; space >= 0; space--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (pound = 0; pound < i + 2; pound++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int towerheight(void)
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("Your number must be between 1 - 23: ");
        num = GetInt();
    }
    while (num <= 0 || num >= 24);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In function return should be `return num` not `return 0`

Comment: Learn how to debug instead posting on SO for the tiniest of problems. If you stepped through the code in a debugger you would see that `height` is zero, so your `for` loop doesn't even run because it fails the `i < height` condition off the bat.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your function, replace the last line:

```
int towerheight(void)
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("Your number must be between 1 - 23: ");
        num = GetInt();
    }
    while (num <= 0 || num >= 24);
    return num; // replace by this
}
```

You always return `0` and the `for` loop doesn't met the condition because `height` is always `0`.

Comment: He does initialize before using it, the do will run through once before, initializing it before it's used.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am sorry, I have edited my answer